# Docker hangs on the RUN command OSX

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, freeze

I have been learning docker using the docker docs, and first encountered a problem in the quick start guide to Django. The program would build normally up until the the second to last command. Here is my dockerfile and the output:

```
FROM python:3.5.2
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code
```

Then when I run:

```
docker-compose run web django-admin startproject src .
```

I get the whole thing built and then it hangs:

```
Installing collected packages: Django, psycopg2
Running setup.py install for psycopg2: started
Running setup.py install for psycopg2: finished with status 'done'
Successfully installed Django-1.10.5 psycopg2-2.6.2
```

So since I don't have experience with compose I tried the most basic docker build that included a dockerfile. This one also got hung up.

```
FROM docker/whalesay:latest
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y fortunes
CMD /usr/games/fortune -a | cowsay
```

And this is the last terminal line before the hang.

```
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
```

According to the tutorial this occurs in the same spot. The second to last command, which happens to also be RUN.

```
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
---> dfaf993d4a2e
Removing intermediate container 05d4eda04526
[END RUN COMMAND]
```

So thats why I think its in the RUN command, but I'm not sure why or how to fix it. Does anyone know why this might be occurring? I am using a Macbook Pro 8.1 running OSX EL CAPITIAN version 10.11.6 and Docker version 1.13.1, build 092cba3